# Printing a large array of strings but limiting it to 40 characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print an array which contains a number of strings but i only want the console to output up to 40 characters. This is the code i've tried so far.

```js
var words = ["As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice"];
var wordToPrint = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  wordToPrint += words[i];
  for (var j = words.length; j < 40; j++) {

    console.log(wordToPrint.split(","));
  }
}
```

Comment: splitting on comma??? So how about substring() or substr()

Comment: you need to use `words[i].length`

Comment: `words.join(' ').substingr(0, 39)`

Comment: `console.log(words.join().substr(0,40))` ?

Comment: Take a look at JavaScript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s.

Comment: Do you need to keep words intact?

Comment: no i do not. Thanks for all the help so far! really great community

Answer (score 1):

So I'm now guessing, you want to split the text into lines of text, 40 characters in length each.

You may do it with regex, where you select between 1 and 40 characters, until you run out of letters.

```js
var words = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice"];

console.log(words.join().match(/.{1,40}/g));
```

result:

```
[
  "Lorem,Ipsum,As,Gregor,Samsa,Vicky,Is,Coo",
  "l,Greg,Nice,As,Gregor,Samsa,Vicky,Is,Coo",
  "l,Greg,Nice,As,Gregor,Samsa,Vicky,Is,Coo",
  "l,Greg,Nice"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) over words array to join them in a string and use [`substring(start, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to slice upto limit.

```js
var words = ["As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice", "As", "Gregor", "Samsa", "Vicky", "Is", "Cool", "Greg", "Nice"];

console.log(words.join(' ').substring(0, 40));
```

Comment: Thankyou for that, my problem is it will just print the same 40 characters over and over. Testing reveals that it gets up to As and then thats it.

Comment: @GregoryYates - did you mean that you wanted to print the entire array with 40 characters per line?

Comment: The above code will print only first 40 characters, if you want to print the entire array, use a for loop and keep increment your iterator value by 40.

Comment: Yes, sorry i feel like i've explain my issue in the same way someone who has never spoken english before would go about it. But yea basically it needs to print out just 40 characters per line until the array end is reached and then that's it.